# discard packets based on their MAC adress

Tags: windows-7, networking, lan, mac-address

suppose we're on LAN network, and I am running a windows 7

- I wonder if there is a way to discard all packets received from a specific node which I know its MAC address

Comment: Its possible in almost and I quote "almost" every firewall, and its even default buildin in a Linux distribution.

Comment: @DylanRz , is there a software that can do that  ?

Comment: Windows has no software that can do such a thing. You would either have to use linux or a bought firewall between you and the network.